# paracol environment doesn't work inside minipages

Tags: minipage, paracol

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\typesetparacol{%
    \begin{paracol}{2}%
        \lipsum[1]%
        \switchcolumn%
        \lipsum[2]%
    \end{paracol}%
}

\begin{document}%
    \typesetparacol%
    \newpage%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \typesetparacol%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

The first time, `paracol` works as usual:[image: <code>paracol</code> environment outside of any minipage]

The second time, however, the text isn't arranged in columns:[image: <code>paracol</code> environment inside a minipage]

The problem is definitely not limited to `paracol`, but I cannot find the reason. Could you give an explanation and, if possible, provide a solution?

Comment: column breaking is effectively the same as page breaking, but two "pages" are merged in to one, a minipage stops all page breaking so more or less by design it stops column breaking as well.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If so, could you post it as an answer to your own question?

Comment: @miestasmia No, I didn't. IIRC, this would have been a part of an implementation of dynamically-sized pages, which I ended up programming in Lua.